# assertionerror returning empty string in python

Tags: python, assert

I am doing this:

```
try: self.failUnless(sel.is_text_present("F!")) #sel.is_text_present("F!") is false
except AssertionError, e: 
    print("x"+e+"y")
    sys.exit()
```

it is printing nothing except xy. no class name or anything else. what does the error in AssertionError normally contain?

edit: apparently the user provides its own message. selenium generated many of these:

```
except AssertionError, e: self.verificationErrors.append(str(e))
```

without sending in a message at all, so it appends a bunch of empty strings to verificationErrors.

Comment: What's worse, any exception without a message will have empty representation, e.g. `raise ValueError`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't catch the errors from assertions. All the assertions in the unittest module take a final parameter, `msg`, which is the message to be raised if the assertion fails. Put your debugging there if necessary.

Comment: nooooooooooo. i have 30 files with lots of asserts generated from selenium. all of them are like this. whenever an assert fails for a particular test, i'm left dumbfounded as to the reason the assert failed.

Answer (score 4):

Standard `assert` statement doesn't put anything into the `AssertionError`, it's the traceback that matters. There is a `assert expr, msg` variant that sets the error message, if you're using unittest, then the second argument of `assertTrue` (`failUnless` is deprecated) will do it.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you want to use your assertions as debug statements in the event of a failure. This should help...

```
import traceback

try:
  assert 1 == 2
except AssertionError: 
  traceback.print_exc()
```

This prints:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./foo.py", line 4, in <module>
    assert 1 == 2
```